# When do you need to use ssh for sending data to a db?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssh

This may be a dumb question to most of you but I am lost with understanding when you would need to use ssh(secure shell) to access a remote server. Using a MySQL database do you need to open port 3306 by default or change any settings in MySQL, in order for you to send data to your database via a webpage. What prompted this question is I am working on a webpage with a star rating system and I was having an issue where when you click on a star to rate an item that rating is not being stored in the database. If I manually put ratings in using phpmyadmin the results of those ratings show up on the page, but still when I click the stars to rate it's like I'm not able to use 'INSERT INTO' to put data into the database. From reading around and asking another question on here it led me to believe that I need to set up 'ssh'? to access my testing server to 'open up port 3306'so that I can send data to my database from my page. Does this sound correct to any of you? Here is one of the links where I was getting this idea from = http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html.

If not, does it look like I have something wrong with my code keeping it from working on the code end of things?

```
<?php $ratingData = Rating::OutputRating('cams');
        if (Error::HasErrors())
        {
        echo Error::ShowErrorMessages();
        Error::ClearErrors();
         }
        else
        {
            echo $ratingData;
        }
        ?>
```

Above is the code that is placed in my page where I want the rating system to display.

```
    class Rating
  {
  // Output the Rating information
  // Returns a string of HTML
  public static function OutputRating($varItem)
  {
    // Verify $varItem was provided
    if ($varItem != null && strlen(trim($varItem)) != 0)
    {
      // Information for the Output
      $averageStars = Rating::CalculateAverageRating($varItem);

      // Check to see that the user has not already rated this item
      if (Rating::CheckRatingsByIp($varItem) == 0)
      {
        $classes      = "rating " . Rating::ShowStars($averageStars);

        // Write Output HTML for the Rating Data
        $output  = "\r\n";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"{$classes}\" id=\"{$varItem}\">\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"one\"><a   href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 1);\" title=\"1 Star\">1</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"two\"><a   href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 2);\" title=\"2 Stars\">2</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"three\"><a href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 3);\" title=\"3 Stars\">3</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"four\"><a  href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 4);\" title=\"4 Stars\">4</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"five\"><a  href=\"javascript:RateItem('{$varItem}', 5);\" title=\"5 Stars\">5</a></li>\r\n";
        $output .= "</ul>\r\n";
      }
      else
      {
        $classes      = "rated " . Rating::ShowStars($averageStars);

        // Write Output HTML for the Rating Data
        $output  = "\r\n";
        $output .= "<ul class=\"{$classes}\" id=\"{$varItem}\">\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"one\">1</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"two\">2</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"three\">3</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"four\">4</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "  <li class=\"five\">5</li>\r\n";
        $output .= "</ul>\r\n";
      }
```

It appears to my like $rating data will display one of the 2 html tables above, if the user has not already rated that item it will display the first table.

```
    function RateItem(varItemId, varRating)
{
  var varOrigClassName = document.getElementById(varItemId).className;
  // Retrieve Ajax Feeds
  new Ajax.Request('RatingSystem/ajax.rate.item.php',
    {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: {item: varItemId, rating: varRating, classes: varOrigClassName},
      onSuccess: ReloadRating,
      onFailure: RatingError
    }
  );
}
```

Then it will call up the function above

```
  // Check that the data was sent
  if (sizeof($_POST) == 0
    || $_POST['item'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['item'])) == 0
    || $_POST['rating'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['rating'])) == 0
    || $_POST['classes'] == null
    || strlen(trim($_POST['classes'])) == 0)
  {
    die("You shouldn't be attempting to access this file in this manner.");
  }

  echo Rating::RateItem($_POST['item'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['classes']);
?>
```

Which leads to this chunk of code above

```
public static function RateItem($varItem, $varRating, $varClasses)
      {
        $newClassNames = $varClasses;

        // Verify $varName was provided
        if ($varItem != null && strlen(trim($varItem)) != 0
          && $varRating != null && strlen(trim($varRating)) != 0 && is_numeric($varRating) 
      && $varClasses != null && strlen(trim($varClasses)) != 0)
    {

      // Check to see that the user has not already rated this item
      if (Rating::CheckRatingsByIp($varItem) == 0)
      {
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        Database::ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO `rating` (`item_name`, `rating`, `ip_address`, `date_rated`) VALUES ('{$varItem}', {$varRating}, '{$ipAddress}', NOW())", "InsertRating");
        Database::FetchResults("InsertRating");
        Database::FreeResults("InsertRating");
        Database::RemoveSavedResults("InsertRating");
```

And then to this function where it will insert that data into my table. I got the code for this star rating system from this source = http://www.search-this.com/2007/06/04/css-the-star-matrix-pre-loaded-part-2/.